# Is there a better way to optimise this Firestore Query?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Right now I query Firestore arrays based on another array of strings. This works fine but I would like to know if this is correct and if there is a way to optimise it to make it faster.

Here is my code.

```
var exampleArray = [test]()

func loadData(textArray : [String]){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        for i in 0..<textArray.count{
            db.collection("testCollection").whereField("testField", arrayContains: textArray[i]).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Test Error")
                } else {
                    if (querySnapshot!.isEmpty == false){
                        let res = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({test(dictionary: $0.data())})
                        self.exampleArray.append(contentsOf: res)
                        self.summaryTableView.reloadData()
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        print(self.textArray[i])

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Some info:

- Right now the VisionCloudRecognition process and query take about 10-11sec. 7 sec the recognition and 3-4 the query.
- The Database has 7700 documents, 7 fields each.

Basically my app does the following:

- User takes a photo
- With OCR the image becomes text and i append the text in an array of strings.We don't know how many strings are going to be. Maybe 0 or maybe 50.
- Then i query Firestore arrays based on the array of strings.

Comment: It seems pretty standard to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am not liking `self.summaryTableView.reloadData()` and `SVProgressHUD.dismiss()` being called repeatedly within the loop. If the textArray has 50 elements and each query returns 100 documents that will refresh the tableView 5000 times unnecessarily and call SVProgressHUD.dismiss() as well. I would load your data and move the reloadData() outside that loop. I might even suggest a restructuring of the data or perhaps denormalizing it a bit to load that data more quickly. But, the question doesn't tell us your current structure or what your use case is.

Comment: You're calling `reloadData` once per query. If the array has 50 elements, you're calling `reloadData` 50 times. If you want to reduce, you can count how many queries you've already fired, and only call `reloadData` after number 50.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your answers.So you are telling me that i have to use a DispatchGroup to reload data and dismiss the SVProgressHUD?

Comment: Ok so when i use `DispatchQueue.main,async` to `reloadData` and dismiss the HUB i cant see anything on the tableView because this runs before the query.

Comment: When responding to comments be sure to at a @ in front of the name you're replying to so it gets their attention. Like @NickStefanidis

Comment: And no, do not at a dispatchQueue. Conceptually you would want to load your data first, then reload the tableview to display it. The issue here is the loop is outside the query so there's no opportunity to reload the data after the loop. To handle that, you need to add an if statement around the tableView.reloadData so it will only fire on the last iteration of the loop. Something like `if i == last index in the array then reload the tableview` so the tableView reload will only happen once after all of the data has been loaded.

Comment: @Jay Oh i get. This will also reduce time?

Comment: Time is relative. Even with dozens of calls that code should run almost instantaneously - it does in my testing. Not making a UI call repeatedly is just good coding and yes, it would reduce it but I am curious as to what kind of delays you are encountering as we may be all off base and the problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @Jay thank you. right now the VisionCloudRecognition process and query take about 10-11sec. I just dont know if this a good time or not. 7 sec the recognition and 3-4 the query.

Comment: ok - thats good info to include in the question. Some additional info may lead to a solution; how much data is being loaded? In other words can you give us an indication of what it in your [ example ] array? How many elements? Then a snapshot of your testCollection would be useful along with some information about how much data is being retrieved. For example, when I tested your code, I added 10 strings to the example array and each query returned 10 documents. It completed in under a second. Can you update your question with that additional info?

Comment: @Jay i updated my question.

Comment: Based on that info, are you saying the strings stored in the array represent images which could be megabytes in size, and the queries are also returning documents that contain strings that could be megabytes in size?

Comment: @Jay No no, of course not. The image contains text and with ocr i store the text in an array.

Comment: One item I asked for was how much data is being retrieved per loop iteration. In other words, whether the database has 7700 or 77000 documents isn't relevant. What is important is how many documents a single query would return on average. So let's say first time through the loop the query is for a string matching 'A' - how many documents would, in their array, have a matching letter 'A' and be returned? 10? 1000?. I'm trying to get some data points so I can test it here.

Comment: @Jay . Oh ok i got. Every loop 1 document. 1 loop 1 document, 2 loops 2 documents etc.(if matching).

Comment: OK. I crafted an app that creates 7700 documents within a collection. Each document contains an array field with 10 elements (just random words). I then have an array of 100 words I want to query for - that's your `testArray`. Each query could return up 10 documents (yours returns 1 per). I ran the test 10 times using your query but not including the .reloadData and .dismiss and the total average time for the query is 1.6 seconds. So there you have a comparison. Try removing those functions from your code and see if its any faster. If not, something else is causing the delay.

Comment: @Jay ill do that. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're running a bunch of async requests in a loop (that's always bad) and you're reloading the data as each one resolves causing the `tableView` to keep repainting with new data.

What you want to do is add all of those db requests to a `DispatchGroup`. As they resolve, add the data to your array. Once they have all finished, do a single `tableView.reloadData()` and dismiss your `SVProgressHud`.

This should not only speed things up because multiple calls can happen in parallel, but your user will not have table rows bouncing around as new data is added and the `tableView` reloads X number of times in rapid fire.

**EDIT:** You asked for an example - this is very quick and written here on SO, so look for XCode to notify you of any typos or errors.

```swift
class MyVC: UIViewController {

  var exampleArray = [test]()
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

  override func viewDidLoad(animated: bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)

    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    for i in 0..<textArray.count {
      getTestFieldRecords(i)
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
      self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  private func getTestFieldRecords(_ record: Int) {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    db.collection("testCollection").whereField("testField", arrayContains: textArray[i]).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
        print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
        print("Test Error")
      } else {
        // rest of your code because I'm too lazy to format it
      }
      self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
  }

}
```

Make sure you call `leave()` every time - error or not. The `DispatchGroup` will not finish until all `enter()` commands are finished with a `leave()` command. Hope this helps point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is possible to edit with a piece of code, cause i cant quite understand how to add the db request to a DispatchGroup.

Comment: Note: I would really like to see your answer as a code snippet as it may be 100% the right answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Very good answer and will help with flicker on the tableView. It also seems to be a bit faster as well.

Comment: @Jay I just test it and its amazing answer. Thank you guys for your time and help.

Comment: One last question. I have a problem with the SVProgressHUD.show(). where should I place it? Because in the ViewDidLoad doesn't work.

Comment: You’ll probably want it in viewdidappear but you only want it when the data is loading, so maybe also have an isLoading Boolean that you set when you start loading and toggle to false when you’re done. When the view appears, check isLoading and if true, show the hud. When loading is done, set isLoading to false and dismiss the hud.